# Dynamic Fields in Django Admin Page

Tags: django, admin, survey

I'm trying to create an interface for the admin page of my app, where new fields are added to the template on input of the admin. For this purpose there should be an option " Add Text Question " or " Add Numerical Question". Afterwards the class TextQuestion or NumericalQuestion should appear, so that you can build a sequence of questions. Does Django offer such an option? Unfortunately I didn't find a possibility for it while surfing the internet.

```html
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [

        ("General",             {'fields': ['question','question_type']}),
        ("Text Question",       {'fields': ['text_answer']}),
        ("Numerical Question",  {'fields': ['numerical_answer_lower','numerical_answer_upper']}),
        ("Scheduling",          {'fields': ['schedule']})

    ]
admin.site.register(M1_Question,QuestionAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the models. The least effort would be:

#### Model `Question`

with fields like:

- type (general, text, numerical, scheduling): a choice field using an enum
- questionnaire: ForeignKey

In this case, the admin list view would show the list of questions and via the "Add Question" button you can simply add new questions and select their type.

These questions could also have a foreign key to a model that holds a list of questions - like for example a Questionnaire. The questionnaire would by Django convention automatically get a reverse relation as attribute: `question_set`.

#### M2M Relation with Admin Inlines

If you rather have the Questionnaire having a reference to its questions (you have not added enough information in your question, so this is just an assumption), you would define fields like:

- questions: ManyToManyField(Question)

and in this case, you could use [Admin Inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) that would allow to add, edit and delete from the list of questions on the detail view of the Questionnaire model object.